# Parsing invalid HTML with jQuery, without adding to DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm working on a jQuery plugin that uses an HTML template. End users may pass in a template that looks at the simplest level like this:

```
<template>
   <img src="/images/image_{field_id}.gif">
</template>
```

The template is supposed to be commented out, so that the browser won't try to render anything, My code just extracts the interior of the comment as text, and then uses jQuery to parse it into an element tree. Then I do specific substitutions.

I remember reading that jQuery just uses the DOM to parse HTML, e.g. when you just do

```
var x = $(html_string);
```

jQuery is actually just adding it to the DOM to get the elements. The simple action above would not render anything (until I actually added `x` somewhere in the DOM), but yet this code results in the browser trying to load the image target - *even if I never add it to the DOM.* Here is a simple demonstration of this effect in action: http://jsfiddle.net/b5HGU/

So basically - is there any way to solve this problem? Can you create an "image" element with a known bad `src` tag using jQuery, but have it not load the image until you actually add it to the real DOM?

The other alternative I have is to complete all the parsing on the template, as a string, *before* using jQuery to construct a DOM. This is certainly doable, but in reality the template has a number of different components, and it is very convenient to use jQuery selectors to turn it into a navigable tree before outputting the parsed version. I'd have to basically write my own XML parser otherwise. Just wondering if there are any simple solutions before I do this the hard way.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your template with a `<script>` tag? I know that jTemplate uses `<textareas>` to get around the issue you're talking about

Comment: @Amin: He wants to avoid rendering when parsing it into a DOM tree.

Comment: Ahh..well then.. i stand corrected :)

Comment: Not familiar with jTemplates, I just looked at the docs briefly and it's not clear to me how it works. If the markup they're showing in the examples is just supposed to be included inline in your HTML, i'd think it would also be causing errors. Or do you mean they advise surrounding it with script or textarea tags to avoid this? Anyway my problem isn't when the HTML is initially loaded, as it's expected to be commented out, it's in parsing that string afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `$.parseXML`, which should treat it as raw markup without interpreting anything.

I suspect that it will need to be well-formed.

Comment: Seems like it's *almost* there, but I get a really strange error when trying to append something in a simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/b5HGU/7/  thoughts?

Comment: And yes - it will always be valid XML, so in theory it should work fine.

Comment: @jam: You can't append XML to the DOM.  You'll need to re-parse it as HTML.

Comment: After trying it, I might retract that.  After fixing the invalid XML, your code works fine.

Comment: Oops - I thought I did that, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/b5HGU/9/ but still same problem.

Comment: Oh, argh. Of course <img ..> is not valid XML. So actually this is going to be a bit of a nonstarter...

Answer (score 1):

It's very old thread, but i ran just the same problem today. I found somewhat solution for this - parsing html with jquery without loading all these assets, images etc. It's not the most elegant solution, but it works anyway.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
//i assume your html-string is in resp variable
var doc = parser.parseFromString(resp, "text/html");
// here just css-select your element with standard method
var div = doc.querySelector('#mydiv');
// then you can wrap this element with jquery and do what you want
var $div = $(div);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I like that `DOMParser`, as this seems to fix a bunch of issues in invalid HTML code. Even `jQuery('#some-id').after(doc.activeElement.innerHTML)` does no longer complain about it.